# Problema com cookie

Tags: php, script

Gostaria que meu script verificasse a existência do informado Cookie e caso não existisse inserisse,e caso já fosse existente não inserisse.

Meu código é esse:

```
$protocol    = (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === true) ? 'https' : 'http';
$host        = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri        = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_uri = $protocol . '://' . $host . $uri;

$current_uri = $protocol . '://' . $host . $uri;
$current_url = md5($current_uri); // SOLUÇÃO

if(isset($_COOKIE[$current_url])) { 
    echo "O usuário já tem o cokkie.";
} else {
    setcookie($current_url, date("d-m-Y H:i:s"), time()+3600); // 3600 => 1 hour
    echo "Cookie inserido com sucesso";
}
```

Porém não tem funcionado! O cookie realmente é inserido. 
**O Problema é que sempre é renovado e não é passado a mensagem de que o Cookie já existe**. 
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Na verdade, peço desculpas, eu não tinha realizado o teste e coloquei o current_url como "testando". Só que na verdade ele representa o URL do navegador. Eu atualizei o código, e você pode ver que não está funcionando. Poderia rever por gentileza?

Comment: Sò de curiosidade, qual o sentido em por um URL completo com protocolo e tudo em vez de um nome simples? Cookies são setados por padrão no domínio corrente de qualquer forma, essa informação é redundante e ainda fica confuso se trocar de protocolo (fora os caracteres especiais para atrapalhar o parse dependendo de como for usar).

Comment: Não está aceitando o valor como sendo uma URL

Comment: @Bacco O motivo da utilização de URL como valor para salvar o cookie é para ter controle de visitação de usuários em cada página que ele visita no website. Ou seja, irei contabilizar as visitações do usuário por página e saber quantas páginas ele visitou. Quando o Cookie é inserido, também é inserido esses dados no banco de dados.

Comment: @Fydellys melhor seria você fazer tudo no DB, e usar um identificador de usuário só. Aí em vez de você guardar a informação no cliente você guarda só no seu lado (a cada acesso do cliente você armazena o URL no DB, com o ID do cookie) - vai facilitar muito sua vida. E sua aplicação vai ficar mais portátil tambem, além de baixar o volume de tráfego.

Comment: Se o usuário tiver 200 cookies do seu domínio, cada requisição para o seu servidor vai transmitir os 200 todas as vezes, para todas as páginas, imagens, scripts e tudo o mais, mesmo que não sejam usados.

Comment: Entendi @Bacco, na verdade, no meu script, eu já armazeno os dados do usuário em meu DB. O problema é que não veio ainda em mente como fazer para que a visita da página que usuário visitou, não venha contabilizar novamente se ele visitar dentro de uma hora. Preciso de alguma forma pegar alguma identificação da página, teria alguma ideia? Tendo em vista que o script que irá registrar tais visitações estaria em require_once no header para poder pegar todas as páginas que ele visitar. Atualmente já pego, IP, URL, Cidade, Estado, Horário.

Comment: Por esse motivo eu quis utilizar a URL para pegar como identificação da página. Entendes? E também para salvar no DB.

Comment: Você poderia simplesmente armazenar `"userid", 278` no cookie, sendo que o 278 seria o ID daquele usuário no seu DB (se não tiver, você cria um novo e armazena o ID no cookie) - pode armazenar algo como userid, 278 - usertoken, 323793 sendo que o Token é um random qualquer armazenado do DB do usuário, assim evita que alguém edite o cookie do lado do cliente e impersone outro usuário.

Comment: @Bacco Você abriu minha mente de forma de um PALIATIVO. Na verdade minha aplicação não tem usuário (a não ser para administração do website). A forma de identificar a página que o visitante visitou. Gerei um token em MD5 com Base na URL e então consegui passar como valor para o Cookie, sem perder a identificação de URL. Fico grato pela atenção. Vou melhorar futuramente esta aplicação seguindo seus conselhos, mais serviu como paliativo. A Solução está na pergunta.

Comment: Se não quiser perder a informação, pode usar um base64 - neste caso, você tem como reverter o formato.

Comment: Outra maneira: Faça UM cookie "Visitados" e no valor ponha um JSON. Aí nesse JSON você vai pondo todos os URLs. (recupera o JSON e cria uma chave com URL e Data. Se for repetido, vai ser atualizado, senão, criado) - Ainda é paliativo, pq continua o problema do tráfego de dados desnecessário, mas facilita organizar.

Comment: Entendi! Fico grato pelo os esclarecimentos. Minha aplicação está com gráficos de visitações, datas, visitas por páginas e ficou muito bom, onde está sendo filtrado somente visita de humanos, bots são rejeitados no script.

Answer (score 0):

**Coloque nome nas páginas**

```
$nome_pagina = "pagina1";

setcookie($nome_pagina, $nome_pagina, time() + 30, "/");

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$nome_pagina])) {
    echo "Cookie inserido com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "O usuário já tem o cokkie.";
}
```

**Se não quiser ficar colocando nome nas páginas, use**  [**pathinfo**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php) — Retorna informações sobre um caminho de arquivo

```
$path_parts = pathinfo( __FILE__ );
$nome_pagina = $path_parts['filename'];

setcookie($nome_pagina, $nome_pagina, time() + 30, "/");

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$nome_pagina])) {
    echo "Cookie inserido com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "O usuário já tem o cokkie.";
}
```